# screen black and blinking when HDMI is plugged

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I own an ASUS KJ550X laptop, 
the GPU is an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 950M (together with the Intel integrated one)
the processor is an Intel i7-4720HQ.
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with Windows 10.

In order to optimize the usage of the GPU, i switched to the Nvidia proprietary drivers (version 346.96).

Now, when I plug an external monitor through the HDMI into the laptop, both screens (external monitor and laptop's one) go black and start blinking really fast. This issue was not there when I used the X.org drivers, but I need to use the proprietary ones (the external monitor used to cut the edges of the screen with X.org).

Can someone help me?
I'm sorry for my bad grammar, english is not my first language, I hope everything is understandable

EDIT: I tried logging in as a Guest user and evrything worked, the screen didn't blink anymore, I don't know why

Comment: I have the exact same issue with 367.35 and nvidia prime

Comment: I have the same on Asus laptop with some GTX card.

Answer (score 3):

NVIDIA has fixed many issues and improved their drivers a lot since the release of drivers 346.
As you have very new GPU hardware use the latest drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch.

Because you did install NVIDIA drivers 346 before, to avoid possible conflicts, first uninstall all NVIDIA software - open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the stable NVIDIA drivers for GEFORCE GTX 950M from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note: When you have had installed **bumblebee** before, this software **must be removed** as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but installing the new drivers didn't change the situation. I tried switching to Guest user and everything worked fine! What does this mean?